# Action который принимает разное кол-во аргументов

Tags: c#

Как мне можно присвоить Action'у методы (разные) с разным кол-вом параметров и при этом параметры разные.

Пример:

`void f1(string s, int i) {Console.Write(s);}`

и

```
double f2(double d, float f) {return d;}
```

Как в простой Action передать сначало первый метод, а потом второй?

Comment: Вы хотите чего-то странного, люди хотят строгой типизации, чтобы компилятор брал на себя часть работы, вы же боретесь с ней... Опишите свою реальную задачу, скорее всего здесь проблема XY

Answer (score 1):

По поводу заголовка....

покатит?

```
private Action<string, object[]> _sampleAction;

public void SampleMethod(string s, params object[] args)
{
  if(sampleAction!=null) _sampleAction(s,args);
}
```

---

А это? Не совсем екшн, но...)

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(IEnumerable<string> param1, string param2, int param3 = 1);
```

Не уверен с экшнами такой синтаксис прокатит или нет.

---

По поводу вопроса в самом вопросе: вообще не вкурил что ты хочешь получить. Но, надеюсь, заголовок построен правильно)

Comment: а как тогда дожна выглядит инициализация?

Comment: Как присвоить тогда метод какой-то.

Comment: точно так же как и в любой другой делегат или экшн. Через `=` или через `+=`. Но здается мне, что ты хочешь лепить какой-то костыль

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите этого:

```
var s="";
var i=0;
Action act=()=>f1(s,i);
var d=0d;
var f=0f;
float result;
Action act2=()=>result=f2(d,f);
```

Через замыкание в лямбду передают аргументы из метода, а потом выполняется какое-то действие.

Comment: Оно то верно, но мне не известны параметры, известны будут только тогда когда будет вызываться Action

Comment: @kitsoRik, Ну тогда в сторону Expression'онов нужно копать и в Runtime генерить Action'ы.

Comment: А какую задачу вы вообще решаете? Почему это все именно нужно вызывать в Runtime. Как вы планируете определить, какую функцию лучше всего вызвать в конкретном случае?

Comment: Есть класс в котором много методов, и должен вызываться один метод, и этот метод выбераеться случайно каждые 15 секунд, а вызывает его другой класс который не имеет понятия какой метод вызывать, вот я и думал сделать через Action, есть конечно в голове идея определить через enum и проверять свичом и вызывать, но думал это слишком затратно т.к. вызываеться метод 50 раз в секунду и классов в таким вызовом будет много

Comment: @kitsoRik, а Action, который принимает на вход массив object вам не подойдет? А внутри лямбды вы разбираете этот массив и засовываете в нужную функцию. По моему самое простое. Подобное Andrew вам привел.